# How to order by a field from the `through` table for a M2M relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django, m2m

I have two models — *Note* and *Pinboard* — with a many to many relationship in a Django app. Those two models are related trough another model — *Pin* — so I can store additional information about the relationship.

I want to show the related *Note* instances in the `DetailView` for *Pinboard*. That's not the problem. But I want to **prefetch** the notes and also **order** them on the `position` field from the `through` table.

Any hints on how to archive this (prefetch + ordering on third table)?

## Example

This is what I have so far… it works in the sense, that I don't have to query for each entry, but I found no way to order the *Note* instances by their `position` without more queries for each instance.

**Models**

```
from django.db import models


class Note(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=200)

    content = models.TextField()


class Pinboard(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=200)

    notes = models.ManyToManyField(
        Note, blank=True, related_name='pinboards', through='Pin'
    )


class Pin(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position', ]
        get_latest_by = 'position'

    pinboard = models.ForeignKey(Pinboard, related_name='note_pins')

    note = models.ForeignKey(Note, related_name='pinboard_pins')

    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

**View**

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView


class PinboardDetailView(DetailView):

  model = Pinboard

  queryset = Pinboard.objects.prefetch_related('notes')
```

**Template**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ pinboard.title }}</h1>
{% if pinboard.notes.all.exists %}
    <ol>
    {% for note in pinboard.notes %}
        <li>{{ note.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% else %}
    <p>Nothing here yet…</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use a [`Prefetch` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch).

```
class PinboardDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Pinboard
    queryset = Pinboard.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'notes',
            Note.objects.order_by('pinboard_pins__position'),
        )
    )
```

By the way, you don't need to use `prefetch_related` at all on a `DetailView` as it will result in the same number of queries.

Plus, [since you're already fetching the `pinboard.notes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/optimization/#don-t-overuse-count-and-exists) I suggest you use `{% if pinboard.notes.all %}` instead of `{% if pinboard.notes.all.exists %}`.

Comment: No magic here :) The `prefetch_related` method help solve the N + 1 query issue but in this case N = 1. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue